# Discord.js. Im trying listen if a user DMs the client and the client will reply

Tags: discord.js

Im just trying to listen if any user DMs the bot aka client and then the client will respond with an embed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the DJS Guide: https://discord.js.org/#/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **messageCreate** event for listening your bot's DMs.

```
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if (message.guild) return;
    console.log(`Someone sent DM to me => ${message.content}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a guild or not.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if (message.guild) {
    message.channel.send('This is a guild message')
} else {
    message.channel.send('This is a DM message')
 }
});
```

Or by getting `null` guilds

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if (!message.guild === null) {
    message.channel.send('This is a guild message')
} else {
    message.channel.send('This is a DM message')
 }
});
```

Comment: `!message.guild === null` would be `(boolean) === null` Do not use `!`